# Add series function in Highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highstock diagram such as below:

[image: highstock diagram]

And I want to add some series to this diagram by addSeries function. But new diagram type is "line". In this case it's return error and does not draw as good as I want.

my code is:

```js
$('.diagram').highcharts('StockChart', {
    rangeSelector: {
        allButtonsEnabled: true,
        selected: 6,
        inputEnabled: false,
        buttonTheme: {
            fill: 'none',
            width: 60,
            style: {
                color: '#000',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 14,
            },
        },
        buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '?? ???'
        }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: '?? ????'
        }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '?? ???'
        },{
                type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: '?? ???'
        }, {
                type: 'ytd',
                text: '??? ????'
        }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '?? ???'
        }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: '???'
        }]
    },
    yAxis: [{
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: '???? - ????'
        },
        height: '60%',
        lineWidth: 2
    }, {
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: '???'
        },
        top: '65%',
        height: '35%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
    }],

    series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: data[0].name,
        data: ohlc,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: groupingUnits
        }
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 1,
        dataGrouping: {
            units: groupingUnits
        }
    }],
    plotOptions: {
        candlestick: {
            color: '#009933',
            upColor: '#d14836',
            lineColor:'#009933',
            upLineColor:'#d14836',
        }
     },
});
```

and I call this function when I want to append new diagram:

```js
function appendBollinger (newData) {
    var chart = $('.diagram').highcharts();
    chart.addSeries({
        type: 'line',
        data: newData
    }, true, true);
}
```

Can you help me? Thnx.

Comment: Could you please give the error you are getting? This code by itself doesn't produce any error.

Comment: Its error is : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plotX' of undefined."

Comment: Well I can't see anything wrong with your code. When are you calling `appendBollinger`, and with what data? Does the error occur when you call that method, not before?

Comment: See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxfhLd63/). This is your code. No error.

Comment: Erfan jan, can you at least  post an image of what is going on and what is wrong in your results? I think it may be your data, because Ondkloss has used default highcharts data, and that may be the problem for you.

Comment: I use simple array like as [154.5, 1000, 25.55, 100.5].

Comment: I would add timestamps to your data, otherwise you are adding data for year 1970, something like this: `[ [1431447677986, 154.5], [1431447692208, 1000] , [1431447700975, 25.55], [1431447706928, 100.5] ]` - of course above timestamps are just examples. And regarding error, it looks like you (or Highcharts) are referring to the point which doesn't exist. Live demo may be necessary.